# IBM Worklight 6.2 returns "Service unavailable since initialization failed"

Tags: websphere, ibm-mobilefirst

I got this problem after deploy worklight app inside websphere. I already follow exactly all these steps carefully without any mistakes.

http://blog.revivalx.com/2014/06/18/deploy-worklight-war-file-into-websphere/

When I try to invoke this URL inside my browser, it throw an error.

```
Service unavailable since initialization failed.
```

Already search out the log file, it said like this

```
[10/2/14 17:46:39:474 MYT] 0000009b Authenticatio E com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter isWaitingForInitialization FWLSE0242E: Failed to synchronize application runtime information. The servlet initialization failed and the servlet will deny service. The most common reason is a failure in JMX communication with the ''worklightadmin'' service. You need to restart the web application after fixing the problem. [project xxxxxxxx]
```

Worklight version

```
version=6.2.0
fixpack=00
buildNumber=20140613-0730
```

Websphere version

```
Webspshere Base v 8.5.5.0
build gm1319.01
```

Comment: As usual with your questions, you never both to mention your Worklight version and build number.

Comment: great... now mention the websphere version, and why you're following a guide written for Worklight 6.1 when you're using 6.2...

Comment: and the 6.2 BUILD NUMBER.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing first, you are using an outdated version of Worklight 6.2; download the latest studio and server artifacts from IBM Fix Central.

Second, you are using Worklight 6.2, don't follow guides written for 6.1...
Instead, [follow the official installation documentation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/admin/c_installation.html).

Worklight 6.2 contains a new management service that you must take into account when deploying Worklight to an application server, this is not taken into account in the guide you linked to.

From the error message:

> The servlet initialization failed and the servlet will deny service.
>   The most common reason is a failure in JMX communication with the
>   ''worklightadmin'' service

Read carefully the [Knowledge Center for 6.2](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/wl_welcome.html), then try to install.
Also read this: [How to solve management service not starting up in Worklight 6.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24518336/how-to-solve-management-service-not-starting-up-in-worklight-6-2)