# Timeout while waiting for the management service to start up.120 secs

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, websphere-liberty

I am using the following on Linux

- MFP 6.3
- WAS Libery 8.5.5.6 (core trial)
- Tried with JDK1.7 and JDK1.6 but nothing worked out
- MySQL

I could not see any other error/exception in messages.log except this and I am not sure where to change the 'timeout' value in WAS Liberty profile.

http://pastebin.com/7uuVtjHL (server.xml)
http://pastebin.com/2ScrUQLa (messages.log)

> Exception thrown by application class
>   'com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.isWaitingForSynchronization:598'
>   javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Timeout
>   while waiting for the management service to start up.120 secs. at
>   com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.isWaitingForSynchronization(AuthenticationFilter.java:598)
>   at
>   com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:141)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:207)
>   at [internal classes] Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Timeout
>   while waiting for the management service to start up.120 secs. at
>   com.worklight.core.init.WorklightServletInitializer$1.run(WorklightServletInitializer.java:121)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:798)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve management service not starting up in Worklight 6.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24518336/how-to-solve-management-service-not-starting-up-in-worklight-6-2)

Answer (score 0):

Right now it does seem like you are experiencing the same issue as mentioned here: [How to solve management service not starting up in Worklight 6.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24518336/how-to-solve-management-service-not-starting-up-in-worklight-6-2)

You are currently using IBM Java 1.7 per the messages.log file:
java.home = /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-ibm-1.7.0.9.0.x86_64/jre

Download Oracle Java 1.7 and make sure your java.home points to it. Start the server and see if there are any differences.

Instead, or in addition, you can try this: https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/184195/no-runtime-can-be-found-and-failed-to-obtain-jmx-c.html

In server.xml find the following:

```
<jndiEntry jndiName="ibm.worklight.admin.jmx.host" value="localhost"/>
```

Replace "localhost" with the Public IP address of the host machine and start the server.

Comment: Ok, Thank you.  Let me try

Comment: I have also edited the question with another option.

Comment: Nothing worked.  However, thank for your help or should I create a new server?  or will it 'because of any permission issue but I run as 'root'