# MobileFirst Platform 6.3 installation issue

Tags: mysql, tomcat7, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

I followed the [installation Guide](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_6.3.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/admin/c_installation.html?lang=fr) for IBM MobileFirst Platform 6.3, but I'm stuck with a problem when launching all MobileFirst webapps (admin, MobileFirst console, analytics, etc...). All I got is a 404 error or A "Page not found" after login to MobileFirst console.

My configuration:

- Tomcat 7.0.54
- MySQL 5.6
- Windows Server 2008 R2
- JDK 1.7.0 Update 60
- MobileFirst Platform 6.3.0.0 (6.3.0.00-20141127-1357)

Following JMX parameters have been enabled :

- Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost
- Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8686
- Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
- Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false

Logs:

> Exception in thread "Thread-7" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timeout while waiting for the management service to start up.120 secs.
>        at com.worklight.core.init.WorklightServletInitializer$1.run(WorklightServletInitializer.java:121)
>        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: Provide the full messages.log from the server.

Comment: Here is the file : [tomcat_logs](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_qf_j0D0lVlRXRtdG5ZQUlGbms/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: See the following question and the additional link within it for a possible solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24509338/ibm-worklight-server-6-2-running-on-apache-tomcat-timeout-while-waiting-for

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it didn't help me to solve the problem. I'll try a fresh install on Linux to see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

I was more successful installing MobileFirst Platform on Linux, but I still don't know why it doesn't work on Windows.